# Getting a ref to a React Select inside a React Bootstrap Modal

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-select

I have something like the following:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import Select, { createFilter } from "react-select";
import { Modal } from "react-bootstrap";
function TestModal ({modalProps, selectProps}) {
  const testRef = useRef(null);

 return <Modal {...modalProps}><Select {...selectProps} ref={testRef} /></Modal>

}
```

The testRef is always null - can someone explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is this sentence in the [Bootstrap Modal documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/): "Modals are unmounted when closed."

You need to add `show` in order to mount the modal with its children and initialize the ref.

Comment: Thanks - I need to check the ref using the "onOpened" callback